# android - Displaying large drawable in imageview not working

Tags: android, image, imageview, scrollview, drawable

I have this horizontalscrollview to display my image at the top of a page.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

my image is a PNG image (3735 * 400 ) 51.3 KB
I've tried following this tutorial
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html?

then the image showed up, but it was scaled down.
ex. I want the height of the image to be 1/3 of my screen, but it was just 1/6.

Is there anyway to display big drawable in its actual size?

*For the code when I scale the image.
I used the class BitmapWorkerTask in the tutorial which is an Asynctask.
It calls this function

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
        int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

like this

```
decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, 100,
                100);
```

I know that this change the size of the image to 100*100 px.
But when I changed the parameter from 100 to other number, my image wouldn't show up.
So I stick with them.

in the LogCat it said
'Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (4980x533, max=4096x4096)

When I moved the image from drawable-hdpi to drawable-nodpi, the image became a little bigger, but stil not the size I want.

Comment: Can you put the code where you're scaling the image ?

Comment: Just remove linear layout

Comment: @ShivamVerma ok, please wait.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/images" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Its working fine for me

Comment: Thank you, I've cut out the lienarlayout as you suggest. However the doesn't change the image size.

Comment: I tried your code (without doing any programmatically scaling, right?)  and the image was gone.

Comment: I'm not getting your point what you just said. Listen just take big screen resolution png image & set it to background that imageview.

Comment: I did do this android:background="@drawable/timeline as my image is timeline.png, but the image didn't show up. (It's not in the code above because I tried to set it from the activity.)

Comment: send me image on my email vishal.b@reackinfotech.com

Comment: Somehow hotmail warned me that your email is incorrect and it's failed to send you my email. The picture is pretty similar to this one http://www.noctua-graphics.de/images/download/tex/sky/pano/pansky03.jpg

Comment: Its working. I think you are not using ".png". It may be the problem. Convert it to png first, right now it is in jpeg format.

Comment: You set property scrollbars=none..There is problem. Check my scrollview. Use it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

to

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

and add-

```
android:adjustViewBounds="false"
```